# Merge two A5 landscape PDFs to single A4 portrait PDF

Tags: java, openhtmltopdf

I am generating A5 pdfs and merging them using PDFMergerUtility of OpenHTMLToPDF library. Is there a way we can merge two A5 Pdfs of landscape mode to single A4 PDF of portrait mode?

I am using Thymeleaf to generate and process the HTML template and then using OpenHTMLToPDF to convert the bytearray of pdf to actual pdf.